# Does Ubuntu One have maximum traffic or download limits?

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-sharing

I am planning to share some project files over Ubuntu-One. The files will be 1-2 GB big, and I expect downloads from 1000+ people.

Does Ubuntu One has any traffic or download limits?

For example, if only 10 people can download the project and then a "Traffic Limit Error reached," that would not be adequate for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find any limits listed; though they may have an issue with terabytes of bandwidth used, especially if you are using the free account.  I would recommend contacting Ubuntu One directly at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Answer (score 1):

This was the answer from the support:

We don't currently have any set limits on accounts in regards to sharing
files. If we find excessive use, that would violate our terms of
service, we would let you know. Our terms of service can be found at:
https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/